# Can I extract a (escaped) HTML attribute within an XML node using XPath?

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

As you can see, The XML node 'description' contains escaped HTML, and I need to extract the src attribute of the first img.  Is there any way to do this with XPath?

```
<item>
    <description>&lt;img  class=&quot;imagefield imagefield-field_teaser_astory&quot; width=&quot;481&quot; height=&quot;455&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;http://www.rightwingwatch.org/sites/default/files/images/a_story_rww/roundup_A_.jpg?1383082488&quot; /&gt; Is Trump Going To Run The Country The Way He&amp;rsquo;s Running This Convention?</description>
</item>
```

Comment: You'll need to parse content of `<description>` element as a separate document. What do you use to execute the XPath (DOMXPath SimpleXML, something else)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use basic substring functions:

```
substring-before(substring-after(/item/description/text(), 'src="'), '"')
```

this will find all text between `src="` and `"` in the first `/item/description` text node in document order.